# Get DB file name

Tags: ms-access

Is there any `SQL statement` who retrieve the file name for a `.mdb` DB ?

There is something similar in SQLite: `SELECT file FROM pragma_database_list WHERE name='main'`

I need the same thing, but for Microsoft Access Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need VBA for this:

```
DbName = CurrentProject.Name
```

There is no SQL expression/function.

Comment: I need to run this from a C++ app, so, is there any way to overcome VBA request ?

Comment: Not that I can imagine, sorry. But how can you ever make a connection to it not knowing the name of the file?

Comment: Through ODBC. And my C++ object is connecting to ODBC and do all